# Is it possible to do this in class...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to know if it's possible to do this in beautifulsoup, look at the class.

```
city = soup.find_all("div", class_="pizdz") 

s =0

For I in city:

   C= I.find("a", class="pizdz_{s}")    
   s += 1
```

I tried to do that, but it didn't work. Can you do the same but in a different way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an f-string to substitute the variable. And you need to use `class_`.

```
for s, I in enumerate(city):
    C = I.find("A", class_=f"pizdz_{s}")
```

You can use `enumerate()` instead of incrementing `s` in your own code.

Comment: Not sure about the actual site but you might want to use `{s+1}`.

Comment: In that case you can use `enumerate(city, 1)` to make it start counting from 1.